# Need suggestion on Code conversion to Matlab

Tags: c, matlab

I am new in Matlab programming but have to convert a C program in Matlab. There are few parts which is making me confused. I am putting here the parts for both C and Matlab and looking for your suggestion for improvement of the code because the full code is not giving right output:

C Code:

```
     j = 0;
 for (i=0;i<256;i++){
     j = (j+S[i]+key[i%strlen(key)]) %256;
     int t = S[i]; 
     S[i] = S[j]; 
     S[j] = t;
     }
```

Matlab Code:

```
     le = length(key);
     sc = 0:255;
     output = 0;
 for i0 = 1:255
     output=rem((output+sc(i0+1)+key(rem(i0,le)+1)),256);
     tm = sc(i0+1);
     sc(i0+1) = sc(outpt+1);
     sc(outpt+1) = tm;
 end
```

Comment: Would you show the whole code cause i can't see the `S` array declaration?

Comment: instead of using sc(i0+1) you should use sc(i0) because you are starting loop from 1 not 0

Comment: @rullof: The whole code is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777855/rc4-matlab-code-conversion-not-working). I have inserted some additional code here as well.

Comment: @Bee Is your c code working as expected?

Comment: @rullof: Letting you know shortly. Trying to figure it out.Thanks

Comment: @Bee `sc(i0)` will never attempt to access `sc(0)` because `i0` starts from `1`. If you got that error then you have not copied the code you tested into your question properly.

Comment: @Bee But also, since you're comparing two sets of code, please use the same variable names! This would make it way easier for us to compare the two.

Comment: @Dan: Thank you, I will try to keep it in mind from next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this C code:

```
  j = 0;
  for (i=0;i<256;i++)
  {
     j = (j+S[i]+key[i%strlen(key)]) %256;
     int t = S[i]; 
     S[i] = S[j]; 
     S[j] = t;
  }
```

I would get this Matlab code:

```
j = 0;
for i = 1:256
    j = mod(j + S(i) + key(mod(i-1, length(key)) + 1), 256);
    t = S(i);
    S(i) = S(j+1);
    S(j+1) = t;
end
```

So two issues:

1. `%` in C is neither exactly the same as `rem` nor `mod` in Matlab unless all your numbers are always positive in which case it doesn't matter. If you are dealing with negative numbers then you need to do a bit of research into which you're after.
2. an indexing loop from 0 -> 255 in C should go from 1 -> 256 in Matlab because it begins indexing arrays at 1 rather than 0 like in C.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code but it shows following error: Attempted to access key(0); index must be a positive integer or logical.

Comment: @Bee fixed that ;) try it again. I left off a +1

Comment: Thank you! I must be overwhelmed but new to programming world and only have a C code which seems to work and gives a valid output. In C there is `int i,j=0;
            for (i=0; i < 256; ++i)
            state[i] = i;` when I am trying to convert it to `for i = 1:256 S(i) = i; end` it shows that: Attempted to access S(0); index must be a positive integer or logical.Error in rc4key (line 15) S(i) = S(j);. though I am not using any 0. May you give some suggestion please? whole code: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777855/rc4-matlab-code-conversion-not-working)

Comment: @Bee that's not from the `S(i)`, it is from the `S(j)` - clearly `j` must be zero here. I will update my answer, please check it out.

Comment: Thanks again. It is showing an output which unfortunately I don't know correct or not. I can work out for the other part now - so that eventually the full output can be compared with my working C program. Is it possible for you to check my new question if I give the link here?

Comment: Thanks, This is the new question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854361/need-suggestion-on-code-conversion-to-matlab-extension-1)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the expression `sc(i0+1)` to calculate the reminder you should start the `for` loop from 0.

```
 le = length(key);
 sc = 0:255;
 output = 0;
 for i0 = 0:255
     output=rem((output+sc(i0+1)+key(rem(i0,le)+1)),256);
 end
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying with this.