# Need suggestion on Code conversion to Matlab_extension 1

Tags: c, matlab

This is an extension of the previously asked question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851902/need-suggestion-on-code-conversion-to-matlab?noredirect=1#comment31280378_20851902). In a short, I am trying to convert a C program into Matlab and looking for your suggestion to improve the code as the code is not giving the correct output.

C program:

```
void prga(unsigned char S[], unsigned char out[], int len) {
    int i=0,j=0,x,t;
    unsigned char key;
    for (x=0; x < len; ++x) {
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + S[i]) % 256;
        t = S[i];
        S[i] = S[j];
        S[j] = t;
        out[x] = S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256];
    }
}
```

Matlab program:

```
function [out, i, j, S]=rc4out(i, j, S)
    %for x = 1:length(key) % It should not work here as no key mentioned
        i = mod( (i+1), 256);
        j = mod( j + S(i), 256);
        t = S(i);
        S(i) = S(j+1);
        S(j+1) = t;
        out = mod(S(S(i) + S(j+1), 256));
```

Comment: I think your last statement should be: `out(x) = S(mod((S(i) + S(j)), 256));` and `S(j) = S(i); S(j) = t;` should be `S(i) = S(j); S(j) = t;`

Comment: All the `j` indices need a `+1`

Comment: @Dan : I think its better, to replace `j = mod( j + S(i), 256);` with `j = mod( j + S(i + 1), 256) + 1;`

Comment: @MadHatter Yes you're right. But it should be `j = mod( j + S(i), 256) + 1;` because the `i` should also be adjusted in the same way i.e. `i = mod( (i+1), 256)+1;`

Comment: I think you need to study more about MATLAB coding, because your last question was very similar to this one, and @Dan answered it in very detail, still you asked the same question

Comment: @MadHatter I think you should add that as the answer.

Comment: @Dan : Thanks but I think your previous answer, this answer and _rullof_ 's answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try this it do the same think as the c function: The lengh of `S` should be `>= 256` or you will exceed it as `mod()` could return such index. I suggest you to change `256` in the function with the `lenght` provided to solve this issue.

Here you don't need the `key` variable.

```
function out = prga(S, len)
    i=0; j=0; x=[]; t=[];
    for x=0:len-1
        i = mod(i+1, 256);
        j = mod(j+S(i+1), 256);
        t = S(i+1);
        S(i+1) = S(j+1);
        S(j+1) = t;
    out(x+1) = S(mod(S(i+1)+S(j+1), 256)+1);
    end
end
```

Or you can use the `key` variable to controle the loop

```
function out = prga(S, key)
    i=0; j=0; x=[]; t=[];
    for x=0:length(key)-1
        i = mod(i+1, 256);
        j = mod(j+S(i+1), 256);
        t = S(i+1);
        S(i+1) = S(j+1);
        S(j+1) = t;
    out(x+1) = S(mod(S(i+1)+S(j+1), 256)+1);
    end
end
```