# Need suggestion on Code conversion to Matlab_extension 2

Tags: c, matlab

This is an extension of the previously asked question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854361/need-suggestion-on-code-conversion-to-matlab-extension-1). In a short, I am trying to convert a C program into Matlab and looking for your suggestion to improve the code as the code is not giving the correct output. Did I convert xor the best way possible?

C Code:

```
  void rc4(char *key, char *data){
      ://Other parts of the program
      :
      :
    i = j = 0;
    int k;
    for (k=0;k<strlen(data);k++){
      :
      :

        has[k] = data[k]^S[(S[i]+S[j]) %256];
        }

     int main()
            {
             char key[] = "Key";
             char sdata[] = "Data";
             rc4(key,sdata);
            }
```

Matlab code:

```
function has = rc4(key, data)
      ://Other parts of the program
      :
      :

     i=0; j=0;
     for k=0:length(data)-1       
      :
      :
         out(k+1) = S(mod(S(i+1)+S(j+1), 256)+1);
         v(k+1)=double(data(k+1))-48;
         C = bitxor(v,out);
         data_show =dec2hex(C);
         has = data_show;
     end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're doing bitwise XOR on 64-bit doubles. [Edit: or not, seems I forgot `bitxor()` will do an implicit conversion to integer - still, an implicit conversion may not always do what you expect, so my point remains, plus it's far more efficient to store 8-bit integer data in the appropriate type rather than `double`]

To replicate the C code, if `key`, `data`, `out` and `S` are not already the correct type you can either convert them explicitly - with e.g. [`key = int8(key)`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/int8.html) - or if they're being read from a file even better to use [the `precision` argument to `fread()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fread.html?searchHighlight=fread) to create them as the correct type in the first place. If this is in fact already happening in the not-shown code then you simply need to remove the conversion to double and let `v` be `int8` as well.

Second, `k` is being used incorrectly - Matlab arrays are 1-indexed so either `k` needs to loop over `1:length(data)` or (if the zero-based value of `k` is used as `i` and `j` are) then you need to index `data` by `k+1`.

(side note: who is `x` and where did he come from?)

Third, you appear to be constructing `v` as an array the same size of `data` - if this is correct then you should take the `bitxor()` and following lines outside the loop. Since they work on entire arrays you're needlessly repeating this every iteration instead of doing it just once at the end when the arrays are full.

As a general aside, since converting C code to Matlab code can sometimes be tricky (and converting C code to *efficient* Matlab code very much more so), if it's purely a case of wanting to *use* some existing non-trivial C code from within Matlab then it's often far easier to just wrap it in a MEX function. Of course if it's more of a programming exercise or way to explore the algorithm, then the pain of converting it, trying to vectorise it well, etc. is worthwhile and, dare I say it, (eventually) fun.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But while converting it into int8 it is showing following error: Undefined function 'bitxor' for input arguments of type 'int8. And could you give helpful resource for MEX [I am new in all kind of programming], all I found are either too complex to start with or too vague.

Comment: @Bee Hmm, it should work - [the documentation even uses `int8` arrays in the example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html) - are you on a really old version of Matlab? As for MEX, personally I found Matlab's own documentation and sample code (like the "timestwo" example) the most useful, but if it's all a bit new, definitely get yourself comfortable with structs and pointers in plain C before looking at an `mxArray`.

Comment: I am using Matlab R2011b. I had to use uint8. BTW This above program is of RC4 encryption and I have been really struggling since many days with this. I really don't have any clue why this RC4 is not working in Matlab. Could you see my [full program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777855/rc4-matlab-code-conversion-not-working) and give your suggestion please?

Comment: @Bee Sorry, not sure I can be much help with the algorithm itself - my actual crypto experience covers calling a few API functions and barely understanding how SSH works ;)